# Use div as radio button and change color of div on click based on its id value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a few radio buttons inside a `form` which have `div`s as their labels. I have hidden the radio buttons and am using the following `css`...

```
input[type='radio']:checked + label{
    background: #333;
}
```

to change the bg of the `div`s when they are clicked. But what I actually want is to change the color of a particular `div` based on its `id` value. For example,

```
<input type='radio' name='category' value='1' id='one' >
<label for='one' ><div id='red'>Some Icon</div></label>
```

I want this `div` with `id` as red to have a red bg, when the radio button is checked (i.e., when the `div` is clicked).
Any idea would be appreciated even if it changes the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice, automated solution would be something like this:

HTML

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='radio' name='category' value='red' id='one' >
<label for='one' ><div id='red'>Text With Red Background</div></label>

<input type='radio' name='category' value='blue' id='two' >
<label for='two' ><div id='blue'>Text With Blue Background</div></label>
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(() => {
   var selectedValue = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
   $('#' + selectedValue).css("background-color", selectedValue);
   $('#' + $('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)').val()).css("background-color", "transparent"); 
})
```

When the radio input is checked, the colour of the background of the current div is being set to the currently checked colour (from input value).

Comment: Say I have some 10 radio buttons, I don't want to repeat this code for 10 times, it would be better if it is in a loop...

Comment: By using jQuery and selecting the colour from the input value, you can automate your task a bit.

Comment: This works completely fine, except that the bg color still remains even though the button is unchecked (i.e., some other radio button is checked). I think adding an onchange event listener would help?

Comment: `$('input[type="radio"]').click(() => {
   var radios = $('input[type="radio"]');
   for(var i=0; i<radios.length;i++){
    $('#'+radios[i].value).css("background-color","white");
   }
   var selectedValue = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
   $('#' + selectedValue).css("background-color", selectedValue);
  })`                                                                                                                                                   This is doing exactly what I wanted...

Comment: please optimize this if possible, and thank you for the answer!

Comment: @ShahbazShaik This is an optimized solution you need. (We set the background of all non-checked divs to be **transparent**, and then we change the background colour of a selected div)

`$('input[type="radio"]').click(() => { 
    var selectedValue = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
    $('#' + selectedValue).css("background-color", selectedValue);
    $('#' + $('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)').val()).css("background-color", "transparent");
})`

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!. Please update your answer with this one, I will mark it as accepted...

Comment: @ShahbazShaik I've just updated the solution, you can accept it now :)

Comment: Hi @doxdeveloper, it seems that the above jquery is only changing the color of only first two unchecked `div`s. Please check this with more than 3 btns...

Comment: `$('input[type="radio"]').click(() => {
        var selectedValue = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
        $('#' + selectedValue).css("background-color", selectedValue);
        //$('#' + $('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)').val()).css("background-color", "transparent");
        $('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)').each(
            function(){
               $('#'+ $(this).val()).css("background-color", "transparent");
            });
    });`

Comment: This is doing it, any optimization would be appreciated :)